# Issue with Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my sample data structure and sample data.  What I am trying to accomplish here is to not show customers who have a subscriber record existing with a type of 'Subscriber'.  You will see in the data set that Eli Manning has two subscription records.  One is of type 'Owner' and the other is of type 'Subscriber'.  So, he should not be in my results because there is an 'SUBSCRIBER' record instance.  Odell Beckham Jr. has only one record with type of 'Owner', so he should be showing.

I have tried to use this query, but the results return customer Saquan Barkley.  You will see that this customer has a 'Subscriber' record in the Subscribers table, so my sql is not working as expected.  Any help would be much appreciated.

My Query:

```
select distinct
    a.customer_id,
    a.fst_name,
    a.last_name,
    a.email,
    b.subscription_type
from
    customers a,
    subscriptions b
where
    a.customer_id <> (select customer_id from subscriptions
                      where subscription_type <> 'SUBSCRIBER')
    AND b.subscription_type <> 'SUBSCRIBER'
order by customer_id asc;
```

Tables & Data:

```
DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS;
DROP TABLE SUBSCRIPTIONS;

CREATE TABLE "CUSTOMERS" 
   (    "FST_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CUSTOMER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMAIL" VARCHAR2(150 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMERS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUSTOMER_ID"));

  CREATE TABLE "SUBSCRIPTIONS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CUSTOMER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "SERIAL_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "SUBSCRIPTIONS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")); 

INSERT INTO customers (fst_name, last_name, customer_id, EMAIL)
VALUES ('Eli', 'Manning', '1', 'emannning@giants.com');
INSERT INTO customers (fst_name, last_name, customer_id, EMAIL)
VALUES ('Odell', 'Beckham Jr.', '2', 'beckham@giants.com');
INSERT INTO customers (fst_name, last_name, customer_id, EMAIL)
VALUES ('Saquan', 'Barkley', '3', 'sbarkley@giants.com');
INSERT INTO customers (fst_name, last_name, customer_id, EMAIL)
VALUES ('Evan', 'Engram', '4', 'eEngram@giants.com');
INSERT INTO customers (fst_name, last_name, customer_id, EMAIL)
VALUES ('Nate', 'Solder', '5', 'nsolder@giants.com');
INSERT INTO customers (fst_name, last_name, customer_id, EMAIL)
VALUES ('Patrick', 'Omameh', '6', 'pomameh@giants.com');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, customer_id, subscription_type, serial_number)
VALUES ('1', '1', 'SUBSCRIBER', 'ASDF1234556');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, customer_id, subscription_type, serial_number)
VALUES ('2', '1', 'OWNER', 'ASDF1234556');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, customer_id, subscription_type, serial_number)
VALUES ('3', '2', 'OWNER', 'ASDF987657');
INSERT INTO subscriptions (id, customer_id, subscription_type, serial_number)
VALUES ('4', '3', 'SUBSCRIBER', 'ASDF11223344');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Another tip: Have table aliases that make sense, like 'c' for 'customers'. (Instead of just a, b, etc.)

Comment: `from customers a, subscriptions b` is `from customers a cross join subscriptions b` essentially. You are applying no criteria on how to join the two tables (such as `a.customer_id = b.customer_id`). So you are combining all customers with all subscriptions. You really shouldn't use this syntax. It was replaced with explicit joins in standard SQL 1992 (though it took Oracle nine years to finally adopt this in Oracle 9i). `DISTINCT` is typical sign for badly written queries. Instead of applying it right away, think about what makes its use necessary.

Comment: Do you need `b.subscription_type` in your output? This can of course lead to multiple rows for the same customer. If you need it, wouldn't you rather like a list (a comma separated string with the types) and only one row per customer? If you don't need it, then you don't have to join with the subscriptions table at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have is close to what you want, instead of using `<>` try `not in`, the subquery may return multiple rows and you cannot apply `<>` to it

Ex:

```
select distinct
    a.customer_id,
    a.fst_name,
    a.last_name,
    a.email,
    b.subscription_type
from
    customers a
    inner join subscriptions b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
where b.subscription_type <> 'SUBSCRIBER' 
and a.customer_id not in
(
  select customer_id from subscriptions where subscription_type = 'SUBSCRIBER'
)
order by customer_id asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
  SELECT a.customer_id, a.fst_name, a.last_name, a.email, b.subscription_type
    FROM customers a 
    LEFT JOIN subscriptions b ON (b.customer_id = a.customer_id)
   WHERE a.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id
                                 FROM subscriptions
                                WHERE subscription_type = 'SUBSCRIBER')
ORDER BY a.customer_id ASC;
```

Other than changing your code to include `NOT IN` instead of `<>` (which then includes changing your subquery condition to **include** all customer that **do have** type `'SUBSCRIBER'` among their types), I also switched your syntax to use explicit `JOIN`. Adding to that, you don't need `DISTINCT` if you join your tables correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
    select distinct a.customer_id, a.fst_name, a.last_name, a.email,
                b.subscription_type
  from customers a, subscriptions b
 where a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
   and a.customer_id not in (select customer_id from subscriptions
    where subscription_type = 'SUBSCRIBER')
 order by customer_id asc
```